Disable the linked path when using npm to show the dependencies tree
Now I want to use npm to show the project dependencies tree, this is the command look like:
npm ls lodash

The output look like this:
> npm ls lodash
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: lodash@4.17.21 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web/node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/lodash
texhub-web@0.1.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web
├─┬ @ant-design/icons@5.3.5 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons@5.3.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@ant-design/icons
│ ├─┬ @ant-design/icons-svg@4.4.2 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons-svg@4.4.2/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-svg
│ │ └─┬ svgo@1.3.2 invalid: "^3.0.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@svgr+core@8.1.0_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/@svgr/core -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/svgo@1.3.2/node_modules/svgo
│ │   ├─┬ css-select@2.1.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/css-select@2.1.0/node_modules/css-select
│ │   │ └─┬ domutils@1.7.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/domutils@1.7.0/node_modules/domutils
│ │   │   └─┬ dom-serializer@0.2.2 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/dom-serializer@0.2.2/node_modules/dom-serializer
│ │   │     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ │   └─┬ js-yaml@3.14.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/js-yaml@3.14.1/node_modules/js-yaml
│ │     └─┬ esprima@4.0.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima
│ │       └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ ├─┬ @swc/core@1.4.11 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@swc+core@1.4.11/node_modules/@swc/core
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ ├─┬ eslint@8.57.0 invalid: "^7.31.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@eslint+eslintrc@2.1.4/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc, "^6.7.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@fortawesome+react-fontawesome@0.2.0_@fortawesome+fontawesome-svg-core@6.5.1_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome, "^7.25.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.9.5_react-redux@8.1.3_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit, "~8.7.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@rushstack+eslint-patch@1.10.1/node_modules/@rushstack/eslint-patch, "^4.19.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/dayjs@1.11.10/node_modules/dayjs, "8.53.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/i18next@23.10.1/node_modules/i18next, "^7.12.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/react-redux@8.1.3_@types+react-dom@18.2.23_@types+react@18.2.73_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/react-redux, "^7.7.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/react-syntax-highlighter@15.5.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter, "^3.19.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux-logger@3.0.6/node_modules/redux-logger, "^7.32.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux-thunk@2.4.2_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/redux-thunk, "^6.8.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux@4.2.1/node_modules/redux, "8.21.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/uuid@9.0.1/node_modules/uuid, "^7.1.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+colors@7.0.2/node_modules/@ant-design/colors, "^7.16.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons-svg@4.4.2/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-svg -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/eslint@8.57.0/node_modules/eslint

I just want to show the dependencies tree, how to hide the extra path output? or other tool to show the tree clearly? I have tried to read the help manual like this:
npm ls --help

and did not found a way to hide the extra path info. Maybe using pnpm as the package manager and using npm to show the dependency tree will come out this issue. I also tried to add the depth parameter like this:
> npm ls lodash --depth=1

npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
texhub-web@0.1.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web
├─┬ @ant-design/icons@5.3.5 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons@5.3.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@ant-design/icons
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
├─┬ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.17.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+jest-dom@5.17.0/node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
├─┬ antd@5.15.4 invalid: "^4.8.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons@5.3.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@ant-design/icons -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/antd@5.15.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/antd
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
├── lodash@4.17.21 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
└─┬ rdy-websocket@1.5.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/rdy-websocket@1.5.0_yjs@13.6.14/node_modules/rdy-websocket
  └── lodash@4.17.21 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash

npm info ok 

still show the path.


I just want to show the dependencies tree, how to hide the extra path output? or other tool to show the tree clearly ?

I think you don't need other tools, just use --depth level to 1
npm ls lodash --depth=1

depth 1 will give you only the top-level dependency of a module dependency and hides extra paths
